# String satisfying the condition

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, linear-programming

Given $N$, $A_0$, $B_0$, $L_0$, $A_1$, $B_1$ and $L_1$, find a sequence S consisting only of characters '$0$' and '$1$'(a total of N characters) such that:

1. The number of '$0$'s in any consecutive subsequence of S whose length is $L_0$ is not more than $B_0$ and not less than $A_0$.
2. The number of '$1$'s in any consecutive subsequence of S whose length is $L_1$ is not more than $B_1$ and not less than $A_1$.

Comment: I was developing a solution on the lines of linear programming, but cant build on it, though i strongly feel that linear programming can help.Any hints?

Comment: Is this to be a finite sequence, or infinite? Are there any condition on all those parameters? I think there must be, since it's impossible for some ranges. And what's $N$?

Comment: n is the length of the string, and other variables could be anything.PS: a string may not always exist satisfying the relation, but if it does i am looking a for a method to find it

Comment: There isn't any $n$ in the question. If $N$ is the length of the string, that information should be edited into the question, not buried in the comments. It sounds like this might be a coding problem, not a math problem, and more suited to a coding site.

Comment: Yes this is a coding problem, but with math integrated into it

Comment: And i had added the interpretation of N into the problem.